# Nullreference when trying to set ACL property of new Parse object

Tags: parse-platform, unity-game-engine, nullreferenceexception, acl

As the title already explains I have null reference exception when I try to set the ACL property of my new parse object.

The code is this:

```
ParseObject storeAssets = new ParseObject("StoreAssets");
storeAssets["myKey"]="MyValue";    
ParseACL storeAssetsPermissions = new ParseACL(ParseUser.CurrentUser)
{
  PublicReadAccess = true,
  PublicWriteAccess = false
};
storeAssets.ACL = storeAssetsPermissions;
```

the code looks like in the examples of the documentation but it's not working...
I believe it stopped working with new version of Parse Unity SDK, because the app that I have on the store uses the same code and works correctly.

The code gives me Nullreference exception on the ACL setter.

I am using Parse Unity SDK version 1.6.2

Is anybody else experiencing the same problem?

Comment: Haven't encountered this problem so far. My initial thought would be that perhaps CurrentUser is null? Are you doing a null check before attempting to set the permissions?

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, and all objects involved are not null, all checks are green, I think it's the .ACL property setter itself. Even checking for myObject.ACL doesn't return null... but myObject.ACL = myParseACL throw this error, and myParseACL is not null.

Comment: Hi Benzino, as Jean already said CurrentUser is not null, I remember I checked that. Are you sure you are using Parse Unity SDK 1.6.2?

Comment: And it's still a problem on 1.7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok

This issue is solved. It was a tricky call, because it was due to the Asset store publishing system that corrupted the Parse Package, so you would think you got the latest version of Parse, but it was not the case.

https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-dotNET/issues/155

Answer (score 1):

Since I spent hours trying to figure out what the problem was, I think I will answer my question so that other people that encounter the same problem don't waste time.

I solved the NullReferenceException by downgrading to Parse Unity SDK version 1.6.1.
You can download it following this link
https://parse.com/downloads/windows/Parse/1.6.1

I tried one more time with version 1.6.2 just to be sure. Result is that with the same exact code, in version 1.6.1 the code works while in version 1.6.2 I have NullReferenceException

If you find a fix in 1.6.2 please share it.